# Exponential function and bijection

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am required to prove the following:

For any real number $k$, prove that the exponential function $e^z$ is a bijection ($z$ is a complex number) from the strip $k  < Im( z) \leq k+2\pi$ to the complex plane minus the point $0$, $\mathbb C - \{0\}$.

Any hints please? Thanks!

Comment: Michael, yup, aa was intended to be k, fell asleep on the keyboard:p

Comment: It can't be *any* $k\in \mathbb{R}$, because what if $k=3$ and $im(z)=2$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** To solve $e^{x+iy}=\omega$, write $\omega$ in trigonometric form and solve.

Comment: do you mean w=e^x(cosy+isiny)?

Comment: Given a $\omega$, you can solve $\omega=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$ for $x$ and $y$. You can easely find $x$ by taking the absolute value, and then prove that there is only one $y$ in your domain.

Comment: thank you, but i don't get how is my domain being defined? Also, does this 'absolute value' you are talking about |w| = e^x?

Answer (score 1):

A hint: Don't solve equations, but investigate what the exponential function
$$z=x+iy \ \mapsto\ e^z=e^x\cdot e^{iy}$$
does to horizontal lines $$g_v:\quad y:= v\ (={\rm const.})\ , \quad -\infty<x<\infty\ ,$$ and to vertical lines
$$h_u:\quad  x:= u\ (={\rm const.}), \quad -\infty<y<\infty\ .$$